# ifelse behaviour with which function in R

Tags: r, if-statement

Just been playing with some basic functions and it seems rather strange how ifelse behaves if I use which() function as one of the arguments when the ifelse condition is true, e.g.:

```
#I want to identify the location of all values above 6.5 
#only if there are more than 90 values in the vector a:

set.seed(100)
a <- rnorm(100, mean=5, sd=1)
ifelse(length(a)>90, which(a>6.5), NA)
```

I get this output:

```
[1] 4
```

When in fact it should be the following:

```
[1]  4 15 25 40 44 47 65
```

How then can I make ifelse return the correct values using `which()` function? 
It seems it only outputs the first value that matches the condition. Why does it do that?

Comment: `ifelse` is vectorized; you don't actually want to use it here. You just want a regular `if` statement. `ifelse` will always return a result the same length as the (vectorized) condition you check, which in this case is one.

Comment: You should think of `ifelse` as lining up 3 equal length vectors from which the first (logical) vector is used to pick from one of the other two on a row-by-row basis.

Comment: @joran thanks, this is a very good explanation. Of course I tried with if-then-else statement before and unsurprisingly it worked fine, that's why I was wondering what would happen if I used ifelse instead, but now it is clear. Btw, is there any way to give stars/pluses to comments on here?

Comment: BondedDust and I were a little lazy and breaking protocol in providing an answer in the comments, rather than writing a true answer (below). I will try to write one up in a few minutes and then the procedure would be to accept that answer and optionally vote it up as well. (Feel free to do this for someone else if they write an answer before I get to it...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually don't want to use `ifelse` in this case. As BondedDust pointed out, you should think of `ifelse` as a function that takes three vectors and picks values out of the second two based on the TRUE/FALSE values in the first. Or, as the documentation puts it:

> ifelse returns a value with the same shape as test which is filled
>   with elements selected from either yes or no depending on whether the
>   element of test is TRUE or FALSE.

You probably simply wanted to use a regular `if` statement instead.

One potential confusion with `ifelse` is that it *does* recycle arguments. Specifically, if we do

```
ifelse(rnorm(10) < 0,-1,1)
```

you'll note that the first argument is a logical vector of length 10, but our second two "vectors" are both of length one. R will simply extend them as needed to match the length of the first argument. This will happen even if the lengths are not evenly extendable to the correct length.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you very much, it clarifies everything. If I had more reputation I would vote it up lol.