# Can I replace a vectorized column with another vectorized column using "ifelse" in R?

Tags: r

I tried the below code:

```
Variable<-c("x","y")
Value<-c(0.25,0.9)
Count<-1
df<-data.frame(Variable, Value)
df$col1<-ifelse(Count == 0,df$Variable,df$Value)
```

And I thought that df$col1 would be set to df$Value as the conditional is false. However, it outputs c(0.25, 0.25), which is incorrect.

Am I using ifelse incorrectly here? Thank you!

Comment: `ifelse` will cause vector recycling. use `df$col1 = if(Count == 0){df$Variable}else{df$Value}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifelse(test, yes, no)` returns a value with the same shape as `test`, filled with values from `yes` or `no` depending on the conditional. So here `ifelse` returned only `.25`, the first value of `Value`.

Comment: Wanted to add an insight I found from [this post] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26183904/ifelse-behaviour-with-which-function-in-r) that I found very helpful: "You should think of ifelse as lining up 3 equal length vectors from which the first (logical) vector is used to pick from one of the other two on a row-by-row basis."